# how to hide paths in reference paragraph component

Tags: aem

With the `rference paragraph component` I can display content from other paragraph systems by browsering to their paths. How can I hide certain `content/paths` for the `reference paragraph`? In the attached picture as example, how to hide `Products`?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope my answer will be relevant. 
So to do this, you need to:

1. create predicate for filtering pages to display in dialogue.
2. create your own widget for selecting pages (basing on default one)
3. create your own reference component (basing on default one)

So your predicate can look like this:

```
import com.day.cq.commons.predicate.AbstractNodePredicate;
import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;

@Component
@Service
@Property(name = "predicate.name", value = "myPredicate")
public class MyPredicate extends AbstractNodePredicate implements Predicate {

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(final Node node) throws RepositoryException {
        return node.isNodeType("nt:hierarchyNode") 
            && !node.getPath().startsWith("/content/geometrixx/en/products");
    }
}
```

Row `return node.isNodeType("nt:hierarchyNode")` was taken from another predicate provided by CQ which is called `IsHierarchyNodePredicate`. And we added another statement - filtering by path.

Then we need create our own widget where we will use our predicate. To do this, copy "/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/ParagraphReference.js" into your project, end edit it in next way:

1. Rename widget from ParagraphReference(CQ.form.ParagraphReference) to MyParagraphReference(CQ.form.MyParagraphReference) and register it as a new xtype - myparagraphreference.
2. Add it to cq.widgets category, so it will be available in author mode.
3. In this file you will find next rows:

   ```
   var loader = new CQ.Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
       "url":           CQ.HTTP.externalize("/content.ext.json"),
       "requestMethod": "GET",
       "baseParams":    { "predicate": "hierarchy", "depth": 0 },
       "baseAttrs":     { "iconCls": "page" }
   });
   ```
4. Change `"predicate": "hierarchy"` to `"predicate": "myPredicate"`

Next step will be our component. Copy "/libs/foundation/components/reference" component to your project and edit it dialogue - change xtype of reference node to "myparagraphreference".

So from this moment you can find your component in sidekick and there will not be node "Products".

[image]

P.S.: Also you can just overlay default component with your one and override default widget, rather than create new.

If you have any questions - do not hesitate to ask me.
Good luck.

**UPDATED**